# Is it possible to paginate in jsp with JpaRepository<T, I>

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, pagination

I'm new to Spring boot,

I have a question that, is it possible to paginate table in JSP with `JpaRepository<T, I>`, I've been searching the internet for two days but haven't found one. The Query results were mostly for **Thymeleaf**, but I don't want to use [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#introducing-thymeleaf). I know how to paginate in **JSP** using `Jdbctemplate` but for that, I've to write a query and the number of pages manually. I've already written a spring boot & JSP code.

EmployeeRepository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Emp, Integer> {}
```

EmployeeController:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repo;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showPaginate(Model m, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page) {
        m.addAttribute("data", repo.findAll(new PageRequest(page, 4)));
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="3"
        class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr align="center">
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Designation</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">
            <tbody>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>${emp.id}</td>
                    <td>${emp.name}</td>
                    <td>${emp.designation}</td>
                    <td><a href="editemp/${emp.id}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="deleteemp/${emp.id}" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
<hr>
<!-- Pagination code will come here -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But first you have to make an interface of `PagingAndSortingRepository<T, I>` repository and a controller and in your case I don't see one, you have to add a attributes of page, size, elements, stc which is returned by `PagingAndSortingRepository<T, I>` so your jsp page will get to know the attributes of page, etc and you can use it like `${page}` to show page number. I am referring to this [repository](https://github.com/mightyjava/springboot-pagination).

Employee Repository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Integer> {}
```

The `PagingAndSortingRepository<T, I>` has a `findAll(page)` method which passes the object according to page data.

Employee Dao:

```
@Service
public class EmpDao {

    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository repo;

    public Page<Emp> getPage(Pageable pageable){
        return repo.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

If you want the object according to page then you have to use `Page<T>` interface because A page is a sublist of a list of objects. It allows gain information about the position of it in the containing entire list.

```
@Controller
public class EmpController {

    @Autowired
    private EmpDao dao;

    @RequestMapping("/viewemp")
    public String viewemp(Model m, Pageable pageable){
        Page<Emp> pages=dao.getPage(pageable);
        m.addAttribute("number", pages.getNumber());
        m.addAttribute("totalPages", pages.getTotalPages());
        m.addAttribute("totalElements", pages.getTotalElements());
        m.addAttribute("size", pages.getSize());
        m.addAttribute("data",pages.getContent());
        return "viewemp";
    }
}
```

The `Pageable` is an abstract interface for pagination information

1. `getNumber()`- Returns the number of the current Slice. Is always non-negative.
2. `getTotalPages()`- Returns the number of total pages.
3. `getTotalElements()`- Returns the total amount of elements.
4. `getSize()`- Returns the size of the Slice.
5. `getContent()`- Returns the page content as List.

Jsp page assuming that you already have stored data.:

Just write this in your tables body i.e `<tbody>`

```
<tbody id="myTable">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${data.size() > 0 }">
            <c:forEach var="emp" items="${data}">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>${emp.id}</td>
                    <td>${emp.name}</td>
                    <td>${emp.designation}</td>
                    <td><a href="editemp/${emp.id}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="deleteemp/${emp.id}" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="5">No Users available</td>
            </tr>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

    <c:if test="${data.size() > 0 }">
        <div class="panel-footer">
            Showing ${number+1} of ${size+1} of ${totalElements}
            <ul class="pagination">
                <c:forEach begin="0" end="${totalPages-1}" var="page">
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a href="viewemp?page=${page}&size=${size}" class="page-link">${page+1}</a>
                    </li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </c:if>

</tbody>
```

and you're good to go..

Hope it helps..

Comment: JpaRepository<T, ID> does extend PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  Extend your EmployeeRepository with PagingAndSortingRepository. Then change the findall() method type PageRequest findAll(PageRequest pagerequest).

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Emp, Integer> {
    PageRequest<Emp> findAll(PageRequest pagerequest)
}
```

Comment: So, what do I've to write in jsp for paginate

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods that can be determined through this example.

```
public class StudentRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<StudentEntity> listAll()  {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from StudentEntity");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```